# How to change color of ascroll box or “thumb” within a scrollbar?

Tags: wpf, xaml

How to change color of thump/elevator/scrollbox within scrollbar from grey to red? By default it is gray

```
<ScrollBar Width="10" Height="200" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="VerticalScrollBar" Cursor="Arrow" Minimum="0" Background="Pink" ViewportSize="2"/>
```

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/thumb-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a (complete) custom control template for the `ScrollBar` as exemplified [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2742151d-1fb5-4b3f-9fa3-b41fad8cb45f/scrollbar-thumb-not-working-after-applying-template-wpf?forum=wpf).

Or you could change the `Fill` property of the generated `Rectangle` in the default template `Thumb` element programmatically at runtime:

```
private void ScrollBar_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ScrollBar scrollBar = (ScrollBar)sender;
    Thumb thumb = FindVisualChild<Thumb>(scrollBar);
    Rectangle rectangle = FindVisualChild<Rectangle>(thumb);
    rectangle.Fill = Brushes.Red;
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<ScrollBar Width="10" Height="200" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="VerticalScrollBar" 
           Cursor="Arrow" Minimum="0" Background="Pink" ViewportSize="2"
           Loaded="ScrollBar_Loaded" />
```

Because of how the default template is defined, I am afraid you cannot do this by simply setting some property of the `ScrollBar` element or by using an implicit `Style`.

[image]